# Visual State for MouseOver doesn't work on WindowsPhone

Tags: windows-phone-7

There is the code I generate the button style. I would like to change the borderbrush to YellowGreen during mouseover, but it seems no effected. Would some to show me what's wrong with the code? There is my code.

```
    <Style x:Key="CustomButtonStyle" TargetType="Button">
        <Setter Property="Template">
        <Setter.Value>
            <ControlTemplate>
                    <Grid>
                        <VisualStateManager.VisualStateGroups>
                            <VisualStateGroup x:Name="CommonStates">
                                <VisualState x:Name="Normal">
                                    <Storyboard>
                                        <DoubleAnimation To="1" Duration="0:00:00.5" Storyboard.TargetName="NormalBackground" Storyboard.TargetProperty="Opacity"/>
                                        <DoubleAnimation To="0" Duration="0:00:00.5" Storyboard.TargetName="HoverBackground" Storyboard.TargetProperty="Opacity"/>
                                        <DoubleAnimation To="0" Duration="0:00:00.5" Storyboard.TargetName="PressedBackground" Storyboard.TargetProperty="Opacity"/>
                                    </Storyboard>
                                </VisualState>
                                <VisualState x:Name="MouseOver">
                                    <Storyboard>
                                        <DoubleAnimation To="0" Duration="0:00:00.5" Storyboard.TargetName="NormalBackground" Storyboard.TargetProperty="Opacity"/>
                                        <DoubleAnimation To="1" Duration="0:00:00.5" Storyboard.TargetName="HoverBackground" Storyboard.TargetProperty="Opacity"/>
                                        <DoubleAnimation To="0" Duration="0:00:00.5" Storyboard.TargetName="PressedBackground" Storyboard.TargetProperty="Opacity"/>
                                    </Storyboard>
                                </VisualState>
                                <VisualState x:Name="Pressed">
                                    <Storyboard>
                                        <DoubleAnimation To="0" Duration="0:00:00.5" Storyboard.TargetName="NormalBackground" Storyboard.TargetProperty="Opacity"/>
                                        <DoubleAnimation To="0" Duration="0:00:00.5" Storyboard.TargetName="HoverBackground" Storyboard.TargetProperty="Opacity"/>
                                        <DoubleAnimation To="1" Duration="0:00:00.5" Storyboard.TargetName="PressedBackground" Storyboard.TargetProperty="Opacity"/>
                                    </Storyboard>
                                </VisualState>
                            </VisualStateGroup>
                        </VisualStateManager.VisualStateGroups>

                        <Border Name="NormalBackground" CornerRadius="3" BorderBrush="Black" BorderThickness="1" Background="black" />
                        <Border Name="HoverBackground" Opacity="0" CornerRadius="3" BorderBrush="GreenYellow" BorderThickness="3" Background="Gray" />
                        <Border Name="PressedBackground" Opacity="0" CornerRadius="8" BorderBrush="Black" BorderThickness="1" Background="Red" />

                        <ContentPresenter VerticalAlignment="Center" HorizontalAlignment="Center" />
                    </Grid>

                </ControlTemplate>
        </Setter.Value>
    </Setter>
</Style>
```

The following code to show how I add the button on the MainPage.xaml.

```
<Button x:Name="btnCall"    Click="btnCall_Click" Grid.Row="0" Grid.Column="1"  Content="test"   
Style="{StaticResource CustomButtonStyle}"   />
```

Answer (score 4):

Windows Phone does not really have mouse over.

Remember,on the phone, you don't have a mouse. What is it you are trying to do (in other words, what's the equivalent of mouse over you are trying to mimick on the phone?)

[Usually people interact with the emulator through by using the mouse, but of course there is no equivalent on the phone itself, so it doesn't make a whole lot of sense to support it]

Answer (score 0):

A mouse moves a cursor in an undefined area, thus, it needs to stay grounded on a floor to keep track of a location in the screen that increases or decreases according to the created horizontal or vertical delta.

Touch screens in general are designed to pick and choose locations in an area that is already defined. You don't 'seek' a location with a walking mouse, you already 'know' it. And when you move your finger on your screen, it's to trigger gesture events based on a delta, not to move a cursor based on this delta.